# What the purpose of doing (MyJobject as ILocalObject).GetObjectID

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In delphi Tokyo source code i see this 2 differents way to retrieve a *"service Manager"*

```
var FLocationManager: JLocationManager;
FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap(TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE));
```

and :

```
var FNotificationManager: JNotificationManager;
var NotificationServiceNative: JObject;
NotificationServiceNative := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
FNotificationManager := TJNotificationManager.Wrap((NotificationServiceNative as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
```

What is exactly the difference between these 2 ways ? why in the second case they do (NotificationServiceNative **as ILocalObject).GetObjectID** and not in the first case ?

Comment: I think the first one is wrong. In my own code it looks like this:`LocationManagerService := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap((LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);`

Comment: yes but in the delphi source code they wrote FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap(TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE)); in System.Android.Sensors.pas

Comment: @loki wouldn't be the first time the Delphi source code accesses Android objects the wrong way

Comment: @RemyLebeau i agree but System.Android.Sensors.pas is quite used unit by everyone, so how it's work ? no bug report

Comment: @RemyLebeau : but is it a bug ? because in fact it's work ...

Comment: @loki Actually no, it is not a bug.  There are 2 overloads of `Wrap()`, one for an object reference, and one for an object ID. That is why both examples work

Answer (score 5):

Casting a Java object reference to `ILocalObject` and extracting its `ObjectID` is the *correct* way to convert the object reference to another object type using `Wrap()`.

However, the shorter way *also* works, because `Wrap()` has an overload that takes a Java object reference as input and internally calls `GetObjectID` on it and then `Wrap()`'s that.

So, to answer your question - there is no real difference.  Both ways work.

The longer code might simply be a carry-over from an older version of Delphi?  I don't recall if the `Wrap()` overload always existed.  Certainly in the early days of Android support in Delphi, you always had to get the `ObjectID` manually.  The `Wrap()` overload was likely added later, and maybe not all FMX code takes advantage of it yet.