# Casting a JObject to a JList

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

To cast a `JObject` to a `JList` (or anything else, it doesn't matter, this is just an example), is just doing `JList(MyJobject)` a good way? I don't receive any error, but I'm not sure if it's the correct way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When casting between different object types, you cannot use a plain type-cast.  You must cast the `JObject` to `ILocalObject` and call its `GetObjectID()` method, and then pass that result to the `Wrap()` method of the destination class type, in this case `TJList`, eg:

For example:

```pascal
var
  MyJobject: JObject;
  MyJList: JList;

MyJobject := ...;
MyJList := TJList.Wrap((MyJobject as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
```

Or simpler (which is just a wrapper for the above):

```pascal
var
  MyJobject: JObject;
  MyJList: JList;

MyJobject := ...;
MyJList := TJList.Wrap(MyJobject);
```

See [What the purpose of doing (MyJobject as ILocalObject).GetObjectID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645534/)

Comment: I was certain :) why JString((MyJobject) is permitted (I see it in FMX.InAppPurchase.Android) but not JList(MyJobject) ?

Comment: "*why JString((MyJobject) is permitted*" - it is not. "*I see it in FMX.InAppPurchase.Android*" - then FMX has a bug (wouldn't be the first time) that Embarcadero needs to fix, unless they introduced a new compiler feature that nobody knows about yet. But even so, I don't think it is legal to cast/convert a Java Object directly to a Java String to begin with, regardless of the mechanism used. What does the offending code look like? Which Java API is being used?

Comment: offending code look like: JStringToString(JString(PurchaseDataList.get(I))); with PurchaseDataList a JArrayList, and function get return a JObject;

Comment: On the Android side, `ArrayList` is a Generic class, ie given an instance of `ArrayList<String>` then `get()` returns a `String`, not an `Object`. But that info is lost on the Delphi side, which is probably why a plain type-cast is used instead of `Wrap()`.

Comment: Java generics are purely compile time feature, in Java String is Object (everything is, except few primitive types that you cannot store in ArrayList anyway) so basically ArrayList<String> is ArrayList<Object> at runtime.

Comment: If you use wrong cast for generics at runtime java.lang.ClassCastException will be raised.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar If you go through Java's type-casting system, yes. But a plain Delphi type-cast will bypass that.

Comment: Point is that whether you are dealing with Java String or Object is lost the second you compile Java code. So yes it is also lost in Delphi, but it is also lost way before it gets to Delphi. And how you typecast is irrelevant for that part.

Comment: Problem with plain typecasting is that it only works for the local references during the duration of the native method. If that reference (JObject) must live longer it has to be converted to global JNI reference and that is what Wrap does. Another issue may arise with plain typecast - that particular Java class has not been used before so its VMT is not initialized. That problem does not exist for JString - it would already be initialized by FMX core and typecast JStringToString(JString(PurchaseDataList.get(I))) works properly because retrieved JObject is immediately converted to Delphi string

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible problems with using plain typecast.

First, if particular Java class has not been initialized with previous Delphi code, its VMT table will not be initialized. Next, references returned by JNI calls are local references and they are only valid for the duration of particular native method.

[JNI tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni)

> Every argument passed to a native method, and almost every object
> returned by a JNI function is a "local reference". This means that
> it's valid for the duration of the current native method in the
> current thread. Even if the object itself continues to live on after
> the native method returns, the reference is not valid.
>
> This applies to all sub-classes of jobject, including jclass, jstring,
> and jarray. (The runtime will warn you about most reference mis-uses
> when extended JNI checks are enabled.)
>
> The only way to get non-local references is via the functions
> NewGlobalRef and NewWeakGlobalRef.
>
> If you want to hold on to a reference for a longer period, you must
> use a "global" reference. The NewGlobalRef function takes the local
> reference as an argument and returns a global one. The global
> reference is guaranteed to be valid until you call DeleteGlobalRef.

`Wrap` solves both issues. It initializes Java class VMT if not already initialized and converts local `JObject` reference to global one.

Plain typecast can only work if class is initialized by some previous code and the local reference is not used outside native (Delphi) method that retrieved said reference.

That is why plain typecast used in `JStringToString(JString(PurchaseDataList.get(I)))` can work properly. `JObject` reference returned by `get` is immediately converted to Delphi string and `JString` VMT is already initialized at that point, being commonly used Java class.

When in doubt, using `Wrap` is safer, but it also takes more time than plain typecast.